# Sorting two rows together using minimum number of swaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

An [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PAIRSORT/) question:

My algo is to iterate from 1 to N. in each iteration, I locate the boxes in which the two 'i' are. Eg, for this datam in the first iteration:

3 3

2 2

1 1

I store the position of both the 1s. Next, I start moving that particular i, which is closer to its original position, by swapping it with the larger of the two balls in the box before it. if the box before it contains same balls, then I swap the ball 'i' with the ball in the opposite column. Thus, in the above case, in the first iteration, I swap the 1 in the first column with 2 in the second. Once the first ball i has reacher its position, iI do the same with the other ball i. This is how the algorithm goes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int mark[2][9], in[2][9];
int N, ANS=0, s1, s2, r, t1, t2, v1, v2, p, tmp;

int main(){
    cin >> N;
    for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i)cin >> in[0][i] >> in[1][i];  //Inputting 

    for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i){
        for(int j=1; j<=N; ++j){                         //Searching for one of the i.
            if(in[0][j]==i){s1=j; v1=0; break;}
            if(in[1][j]==i){s1=j; v1=1; break;}
        }
        in[v1][s1]=1234;                                 //temporarily removing the i found. 
        for(int j=1; j<=N; ++j){                         //finding the other i
            if(in[1][j]==i){s2=j; v2=1; break;}
            if(in[0][j]==i){s2=j; v2=0; break;}
        }
        in[v1][s1]=i;                                          //restoring previous i

        if(s1==s2){                                            //Deciding on which i to begin swapping with.
            int m=s1, chk;
            while(m>0 && in[0][m]==in[1][m])m--;
            chk=(s1+m)%2; t1=t2=s1;
            if(chk && in[!v1][m]<in[!v2][m]){r=v2; v2=v1; v1=r;}
            else if(!chk && in[v1][m]<in[v2][m]){r=v2; v2=v1; v1=r;}
        }
        else{
            if(s1>s2){r=v2; v2=v1; v1=r;}
            t1=(s1<s2)?s1:s2; t2=(s1<s2)? s2:s1;
        }

        r=v1;
        while(t1>i){                                          //moving the first i to required position.
            if(in[0][t1-1]>in[1][t1-1])p=0;
            else if(in[0][t1-1]<in[1][t1-1])p=1;            //Deciding on the balls to swap.
            else p=!r;

            tmp=in[p][t1-1]; in[p][t1-1]=in[r][t1]; in[r][t1]=tmp; //Swapping
            r=p; t1-=1; 
            ANS+=1;                                      //incrementing swaps.
        }

        r=v2;                                            //Doing the same for the second i.
        while(t2>i){                         
            if(in[0][t2-1]>in[1][t2-1])p=0;
            else if(in[0][t2-1]<in[1][t2-1])p=1;
            else p=!r;
            tmp=in[p][t2-1]; in[p][t2-1]=in[r][t2]; in[r][t2]=tmp;
            r=p; t2-=1; ANS+=1;
        }
    }
    cout << ANS << '\n';          //Printing the answer.
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting Wrong answer for this, but my code works for the sample test cases as well as custom test cases. Could some test cases be pointed out for which my program fails or point out errors in my algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: is your answer meant to have a `\n` at the end? Some of these programs will fail you for extra characters.

Comment: yes. spoj judge states that my program fails for the 4th test case.